# hornetq - view the available queues

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I'm working with an application that requires the use of hornet-q's.

It's kind of hit or miss for some reason.  When I create a queue, the first message to that queue works, but a second does not, so I've tried using a new queue for each connection to the REST API that is running on JBOSS.  Sometimes this is okay, sometimes I get 412 - precondition failed (when the same name is used more than once) or just simply 500 internal errors.

The application has a /api/hornet-queue/queues/ path, but it doesn't allow GET requests.

Is there another way to tell what queues are open?

Answer (score 0):

you are leaking a consumer and the message is being held on the consumer..

Either reuse the same consumer, or close the consumer.

in case you require to close consumers like this, set consumer-window-size to 0, so you won't cache messages and waste resoruces.